# Vue.js filter function returns [Object Promise]

Tags: vue.js, async-await, promise, axios

I am new to Vue and for this project I am trying to use filter function to format my time value. Looks like its printing the data correctly when I use `console.log(data)` just before return but when I return, it says `[Object Promise]`. How can I convert [Object Promise] into actual time data?

**JSFiddle Code Link** = https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/j0wf5ohg/11/

**View**

```html
<div v-for="(item,index) in fetchDetails" :key="item.id">
  <p>{{ item.time | formatData(item.time)}}</p>
</div>
```

**Filter Function**

```js
filters: {
 async formatData (value) {
  const response = await axios.get(process.env.VUE_TABLE+'/'+value)
  const data = await response.data.time    
  console.log(data); /** prints out the value as CHRIS **/
  return data
 }
}
```

**Data**

```json
data: {
    fetchDetails: [
      { time: "75", id: 1 },
      { time: "124", id: 2 },
      { time: "93", id: 3 },
    ]
  },
```

Comment: An `async` function always returns to a `Promise`. So the only way to get the actual value is to create a state variable in the component and inject the value inside it where you print the data.

Comment: I am not into Vue but it seems like there are some [pretty strong arguments](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5217) against using async filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting [object Promise] back because your filter is using async which means it is always going to return a promise. The easiest way to solve this is to create a new child component for displaying the time. In that new component, you can call your promise to fetch the time to display from the server on `mounted`:

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7paz265/1/)

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item,index) in fetchDetails" :key="item.id" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
    <p>{{ item.time}}</p>
    <time-component :time="item.time"></time-component>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
var Time = Vue.component('time-component', {
  template: '<div>{{formattedTime}}</div>',
  props: {
    time: {
        type: String,
      default: 0
    }
  },
  data() {
      return { formattedTime: 100 }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    // Make api call here to fetch time to display
    // update state with time returned from server and display that

     /* const response = axios.get(process.env.VUE_TABLE+'/'+value).then(() => {
       this.formattedTime = response.data.time;
     }) */
     
     // example
     this.formattedTime = Math.random()
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    fetchDetails: [
      { time: "75", id: 1 },
      { time: "124", id: 2 },
      { time: "93", id: 3 },
    ]
  },
  components: {
    'time-component': Time
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to fetch the data. Not use filters.

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching/

Answer (score 0):

Your filter function returns a `Promise`, so this error makes sense. Filters in Vue shouldn't be async anyhow. Instead, you could update the items after you load them. Something like this:

```js
// component script
methods: {
  setFormattedTime: async function (item) {
    // Your API call here
    item.time = timeFromResponse;
  }
},
mounted: function () {
  // Load items from API
  this.fetchDetails.forEach(this.setFormattedTime);
}
```

If you aren't loading your `fetchDetails` from the API in this component, and instead you're passing them in via a prop, just update the `mounted` function to call `this.setFormattedTime` for each item.